# SBT 1.x - Update phase long

Tags: scala, sbt

Can anyone explain what SBT  does when it displays Updating ?
I use sbt 1.0.2
For instance:

```
Updating {file:/D:/workspace/myProject/}root
```

can be very long (typically when I have dependencies like Spark

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see this message sbt is resolving your project's dependency graph, and downloading missing artifacts (if any). The full resolution shouldn't actually happen every time, but you will still see the message.

There is currently an open issue in the sbt repository with a long discussion about improving this message and behavior behind it: [sbt/sbt#3122](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/3122). You may get more information there.

If you have any dynamic revisions (e.g. `1.3+`) or snapshots in your dependencies, sbt will check during this phase if there are any newer artifacts for them. See [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Cached-Resolution.html#SNAPSHOT+and+dynamic+dependencies):

> When a minigraph contains either a SNAPSHOT or dynamic dependency, the graph is considered dynamic, and it will be invalidated after a single task execution. Therefore, if you have any SNAPSHOT in your graph, your exeperience may degrade. (This could be improved in the future)

You may also be interested in reading sbt documentation about [Update Report](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Update-Report.html):

> `update` and related tasks produce a value of type sbt.UpdateReport This data structure provides information about the resolved configurations, modules, and artifacts.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer with the links. I figured it was doing what you describe, but on environments where connection is slow or bad, display remains frozen for a long time and suddenly displays all the downloads which can be surprising/annoying. Thanks again for confirming this assumption